# MySQL 5.7 equivalent of Oracle's COMPUTE SUM OF

Tags: mysql, sum, aggregate-functions

I'm creating multiple schemas in MySQL 5.7 to test migration methods and would like to see the size of each schema and the total size as I add each schema.

This query:

`SELECT table_schema "DB Name",  ROUND(SUM(data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024, 1) "DB Size in MB" FROM information_schema.tables  GROUP BY table_schema;`

... gives me this output:

```
+--------------------+---------------+
| DB Name            | DB Size in MB |
+--------------------+---------------+
| information_schema |           0.2 |
| mysql              |           2.5 |
| performance_schema |           0.0 |
| sys                |           0.0 |
| world              |           0.8 |
+--------------------+---------------+
5 rows in set (0.18 sec)
```

How can I also total the "DB Size in MB" column to get something looking like this:

```
+--------------------+---------------+
| DB Name            | DB Size in MB |
+--------------------+---------------+
| information_schema |           0.2 |
| mysql              |           2.5 |
| performance_schema |           0.0 |
| sys                |           0.0 |
| world              |           0.8 |
| NULL               |           3.5 |
+--------------------+---------------+
6 rows in set (0.17 sec)
```

In Oracle, I'd use COMPUTE SUM OF, but I can't find a MySQL equivalent (although I am an almost-total newbie).

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.
Jes

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: ANSI SQL uses GROUP BY with ROLLUP https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html

Comment: @MatBailie, re images, noted, humble apologies. ROLLUP gives me exactly what I was looking for - TVM. (Original post amended to remove images and to show effect of ROLLUP).